# How to Post data to website and get content of website using Web Scraping python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a website and one input data which i need to fill in that website using Web Scraping.I am using post method but i am not getting expected output as i want.
After running the code given below i am getting some data but that is different what i see response of the website using inspect.
Input data is CP Number = 16803

**Code:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
url = "https://www.icsi.in/student/Members/MemberSearch.aspx"
payload = {'dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$txtCpNumber': 16803}
r = requests.post(url, params=payload)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

**Expected Output**

> After Post input data i will get name of user , Address etc

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
r = requests.post(url, params=payload)
```

to

```
r = requests.post(url, data=payload)
```

`params` are turned into query string. In your case you got url
`u'https://www.icsi.in/student/Members/MemberSearch.aspx?dnn%24ctr410%24MemberSearch%24txtCpNumber=16803'`

**Update**

Here is a simple **scraper** written in js that uses [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer).

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const URL = 'https://www.icsi.in/student/Members/MemberSearch.aspx';

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false // for debugging
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(URL);
  await page.focus('#dnn_ctr410_MemberSearch_txtFirstName');
  page.keyboard.type('First Name');
  await page.click('#dnn_ctr410_MemberSearch_btnSearch');

  const html = await page.evaluate(() => document.body.innerHTML);

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Run with the following commands:

```
npm i puppeteer
node scraper.js
```

Comment: getting this TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'body'

Comment: Sorry. My fault. The argument should be `data`. Check the updated post.

Comment: Fix your payload. From a quick look, it will require you to do additional steps. Get the page first and extract all values that must appear in the post body.